# Using the Sketch Widget for ArcGIS JavaScript API, can you manually toggle between the reshape and transform?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the sketch widget for ArcGIS JavaScript: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html

I am building a custom toolbar with additional tools and would like to emulate the behavior of the "reshape" and "transform" buttons in the default toolbar. I don't see a way to do this through the Sketch Widget API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want to use the [SketchViewModel](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch-SketchViewModel.html). When the user clicks your button, call the [update](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch-SketchViewModel.html#update) method.

```
var sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
  view: view,
  layer: graphicsLayer
});
sketchViewModel.update([currentGraphic], {
  tool: "transform"
});
```

Full demo [here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/qBBPyLQ).